# MVC 5 Areas in VB.NET not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Using Visual Studio 2013 Professional, I create a new project.

Choose Visual Basic, then Web, then Web Application. I choose MVC. No Authentication. Create.

Then I add an Area called "Test". A Controller called "Test" and a view called "Index".

I hit F5, project builds and runs and gives me HTTP 404

I do THE EXACT SAME THING (literally the same steps), except choose C# instead of Visual Basic when creating the Web Application. And it works.

Yes, AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() is called. It's a default new project with steps described above, but it's simply not working, whereas the C# version is.

Why is this, how can I fix it? My client needs it in VB.NET, not C#

*edit* Here's what RouteDebugger says:

```
Matches Current Request | Url | Defaults | Constraints | DataTokens

False | __browserLink/requestData/{requestId} (null) (null) (null) 

True  | Test/{controller}/{action}/{id} action = Index, id = UrlParameter.Optional (empty) Namespaces = WebApplication2.Areas.Test.*, area = Test, UseNamespaceFallback = False 

False | {resource}.axd/{*pathInfo} (null) (empty) (null) 

True  | {controller}/{action}/{id} controller = Home, action = Index, id = UrlParameter.Optional (empty) (empty) 

True | {*catchall} (null) (null) (null)
```

[image: structure]

Comment: Did you define an ActionResult in the Controller? And what happens if you try to right click on the ActionResult and click on "Add View..." ? Maybe the folder structure where your view is located is not correct.

Comment: As I mentioned, I added a controller called "Test". In it, I right-clicked the "Index" ActionResult and added a view called "Index". The folder structure in VB.NET is exactly the same as the C# version. Do yourself a favor. Open VS.NET 2013, and do what I did and see.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: I've just tried this on two VS2013 pro instances running side-by-side, one C# and one VB.net; assuming I've followed your steps precisely, your problem didn't occur for me. What URL did your browser open up, and what controllers do you have in the `controllers` folder?

Comment: @AdrianWragg HomeController was created automatically. I right-clicked, added Area called Test and added a controller under the new Area's controller's folder called Test. I then right-clicked, added a new View called Index (as Index is created by default in the controller) and then hit F5, it opened up http://localhost:port/Test/Test/Index

Comment: @AdrianWragg Do you have anything installed like Resharper? I don't. I figured out eventually that it has to do with the lack of Namespace in the VB.NET Controller for the Area, check my answer

Comment: I've a few plugins installed, but nothing like Resharper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25417592/3036342

It highlights that, by default, VB.NET Areas Controllers do not automatically add the namespace, which is required for this to work. After adding: `Namespace Areas.Test.Controllers` to the TestController it worked.

Thank you Microsoft for making this such a difficult and stupid experience.

Comment: Just to be awkward ... I've checked my test project, that was there on my TestController.vb.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Exactly why yours worked. I know ReSharper fixes that automatically AFAIK, that's why I asked if it was there or not.

Comment: No ReSharper, however I do have the MVC 5 scaffolding installed. As your issue seems to be caused by the VB template being incorrect, installing that may fix the problem.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Thanks, going to give it a try. I've apologized to my cat... poor thing...

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing todo with either C# or VB.NET... I guess there´s no other controller in the application; if you have a controller called `TestController` and you´re using the default routing, the one and only available route registered is `test/test`

Comment: C# works. VB.NET doesn't. So how can it not be C# nor VB.NET but another issue as a whole? Please try it for yourself and see?

Comment: It's a default Web Application that's created. So "HomeController" exists as it's the bootstrap MVC5 version that gets installed. I just add an Area. VB.NET project 404's, C# project, created in the exact same way/steps, works. Why.

Comment: It allows me to choose MVC as a project, that's it. Not empty. It's a bootstrap thing they add by default

Comment: I see... in the `New ASP.NET project` dialog, I usually choose `Empty` instead of `MVC`, but check the little `MVC` checkbox under `Add folders and core references`, because if I start with a new project I only want add things I really need...

Comment: I understand. I want the bootstrap stuff though, so chose default MVC

Comment: Using your suggestion of creating an empty MVC project yields the same results. HTTP404. I did add a HomeController under the normal way (see screenshot above) and then added an area called Test as per my steps

Comment: What is weird is that in Route Debugger, it actually "hits" the route for the Area correctly...

Comment: VB.NET doesn't automatically add the namespace to the controller in the Area, that's why it's failing